How to create an new module in Spring6 Source code?
As the title said, I want to create an new module in Spring-Project to debug source code to learn.
So i create a new module named spring-z-simple look like this
IDEA screenshot
And here is my gradle file look like
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.springframework'
version = '6.2.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":spring-context"))
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

After i build project successfully,I try to code. But i get this error in idea when i'm typing
error screenshot
And i also can't find ApplicationContext class in spring-context module, but i have already add dependency in gradle file
I'm confirm that i set the right jdk for this project and this module
And in gradle tool window, my module spring-z-simple has no dependencies of spring-context
gradle tool window screenshot
I have never use gradle before, So what should i do?
I want to debug spring source code

Spring Framework 6 requires a minimum of JDK 17 at runtime, as well as a minimum of Tomcat 10/Jetty 11 (for Jakarta EE 9 compatibility).
This is because all platform modules provided by JVM are observable module. By default if you are creating your module you don't need to require these platform module. Packages exported by these modules can be imported without any require directive in module-info.java file. You can get the list of observable/platform module using this command.

java --list-modules


Thx, I found that i just need to type directly and they will work well, like String or some else java class.
And then there is one problem left that is why i cant found class like ApplicationContext in  my spring-z-simple module or how can i to do that
